# Android TextView new line isn't working

Tags: java, android

I found the Answer I will accept it in 2 days time

I have been trying to create an activity that can display multiple messages for the user, in order to fit everything in the text view I need to create three lines. My search online hasn't given me any solutions, here is what I have tried

Java

```
"\n"
"\r\n"
newLineChar = System.getProperty("line.separator")
messageTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("This\n Is\n A Test"));
messageTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("This<br> Is<br> A Test"));
```

xml

```
android:lines="3"
android:maxLines="3"
```

Misc.

- Hardcoding the string value directly into setText()
- Various combinations of all of the above
- removing android:clickable="false"
- removing android:cursorVisible="false"
- removing android:focusable="false"
- removing android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

Code snippet:

```
// Message passed to next activity via putExtra()
message = "This\n Is\n A Test";
// Next Activity
TextView messageTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageToUser);
String message = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");
messageTextView.setText(message);
```

Current and Updated XML for the TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/messageToUser"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#90FFFFFF"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:text=""
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="165dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="165dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="209dp"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

If this helps, I'm on Windows 7, Android Studio 2.3.2, Java 1.8, designing an App Specifically for SM-T580 (Samsung Tab A 10.1"), the TextView's parent is the base ConstraintLayout of the component tree

Comment: after setting text do like this messageTextView.setText(messageTextView.replace("\\n", "\n"));

Comment: Can you add XML code here for you layout which contains TextView

Comment: Can you post <TextView> xml code here

Comment: this is the best way to manage the textview like padding, and margin propoerty to set message layout .

Comment: your width has to be wrap_content to fit the lines

Comment: @pianoisland Is that run in other device/ version except your Samsung Tab A 10.1?

Comment: @NitinPatel no it is the only device this App will run on, thank you for reading the entire question

Comment: @RajGohel added xml

Comment: @sandeepmaaram added xml

Comment: @Avi added xml to the question

Comment: that's goog but can you attached it with parent layout like complete xml

Comment: @Avi thanks for the feedback but I found the issue

Comment: Do not use `ems` and `inputType`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue I had to take `android:inputType="textPersonName"` out of the XML for the TextView. I had mistakenly left the `Html.fromHtml(...)` method call when I initially removed `android:inputType="textPersonName"`. After calling `message.setText("This\n Is\n A Test");` with NO `android:inputType="textPersonName"`.Everything worked as expected.

For final clarity....

The newline character "\n" will not work if the input type is "textPersonName"

The newline character for Andriod is "\n"

Comment: Thank you for that, this solved the problem for me !

Answer (score 5):

try this \n corresponds to ASCII char 0xA, which is 'LF' or line feed

```
        tv.setText("First line " + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Line 2"+ System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Line 3");


String String1 = "value 1";
String String2 = "value 2";
TextView.setText(String1 + "\n" + String2);
```

**or try this**

```
string = string.replace("\\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

**for hardcore string try this**

```
<string name="value"> This\nis a sample string data</string>
```

**or**

```
<string name="value> This<br>is a sample<br> String data</string>
```

Comment: \n doesn't work for me, neither does System.getProperty("line.separator") The string must be passed in programmatically so I cannot harcode the string into XML

Comment: @pianoisland try this         tv.setText("First line " + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Line 2"+ System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Line 3");

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to set for the **android:inputType** because this is a TextView. These are the steps that I did to successfully implement the new line:

1. Make sure that **android:maxLine** is not set to 1. If you set this to 1, it will not implement new line. [Refer to the screenshot]

[set maxLine inside xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLTHV.png)

2. If you want to manipulate a string that is not constant or not  declared inside your string.xml, put System.getProperty("line.separator") between two string. In my case I put

   **phoneNumber = memberProfile.getPhoneNumber() + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "09162343636";**
3. If you have a constant string or you have set it to your string.xml file, just put "\n" and that works perfectly. Refer sample below:

   [string.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usNLF.png)

I was using a recyclerView to display so here is the output of this:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwCUw.png)

Answer (score 2):

\r\n works for me

```
messageTextView.setText("First line\r\nNext line");
```

**Or alterantively** you can also use string variable

```
<string name="sample_string"><![CDATA[some test line 1 <br />some test line 2]]></string>
```

so wrap in CDATA is necessary and breaks added inside as html tags

Comment: Can you think of any reason why it wouldn't work for me? Would it be something with my environment?

Comment: The \r is not necessary.  Android is Linux based, \n is a newline.

Comment: Which platform are you using for Android Studio? Windows or Linux

Comment: Windows, it was stated in my question

Comment: @JayPatel First off, its \r and ]n, not forward slash.  Secondly, Android is a linux OS.  That's what matters- the platform you run on, not what platform you compile on.  That means you only need the linux newline, \n

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
messageTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("This<br/>Is<br/>A Test"));
```

Explanation: The TextView content is HTML content. `<br/>` is an HTML tag for a line break.

Answer (score 1):

```
messageTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("This\n Is\n A Test"));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this. It work for me

```
message = "This"+System.getProperty("line.separator") 
+ "Is" + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "A Test";
// Next Activity
TextView messageTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageToUser);
String message = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");
messageTextView.setText(message);
```

Comment: how is this different than initializing a variable for System.getProperty("line.separator") ?

Comment: System.getProperty("line.separator") will returns the OS dependent line separator.

Comment: This did the trick for me. I got my textstring from our backend, and the only way to get the linebreak working was by replacing with System.getProperty("line.separator").

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to res/strings

```
<string name="myhtml">
<![CDATA[
<p>This is a <b>bold</b> and <i>italic</i> text</p>
<p>This is another paragraph of the same string.</p>
]]>
</string>
```

Add this your Activity class

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.foo);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.myhtml)));
```

Answer (score -2):

Tried many finally this worked for me

messageTextView.setText(string.replace("\n", ""+System.getProperty("line.separator")));